# Expand $(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4})^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Construct a flow diagram to output the terms of the binomial expansion of $(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4})^n$, where n is positive integer. Test your procedure using a calculator and the value n = 3.

I don't want to do a flow chart but I do want to do the calculation.

This problem has now been solved but I leave the question here, with the edited answer.

My reasoning is: $(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4})^3 = [\frac{1}{4}(1 + 3)]^3$

I have expanded to get

$(\frac{1}{4})^3(1 + 3)^3 = \frac{1}{4}(1 + 3.3 + \frac{(3)(2)(3)^2}{2!} + \frac{(3)(2)(1)(3)^3}{3!})$

The answers are:

$0.015625, 0.140625, 0.421875, 0.421875$

Comment: but 1/4 + 3/4 equals to 1

Comment: How do you get $\frac14+\frac34=4(1+\frac3{16})$?

Comment: Also it's strange that the last two answers are the same.

Comment: @kingw3 not strange.  The ratio of binomial input terms forces equality of the last two components of the cube.

Comment: @kingW3 Nope, it's not strange at all they are equal. The third term is $3\cdot\frac 14\cdot\left(\frac 34\right)^2$ and the fourth one is $\left(\frac 34\right)^3$.

Comment: @Arthur You are right. I must correct for that

Comment: @AzatIbrakov I know $ \frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4} =1$
It mystifies me too. But the book says that and I haven't come across any misprints so far.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. Through your help I have now found the mistakes I was making.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a comment, but I post it here because it's too long to a comment space.

---

Your error is not following the instructions given. The task says: *'Test your procedure using a calculator.'*

Once again: *'**Test** your procedure....'*, not *'replace it'*.
If you did it as described, you would most probably have noticed discrepancy between results and found which one was wrong. You did only half of the task and as a result you have no material for comparison, which prevents you from spotting your error.